# How to create a loop in python that enumerates every day?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a python program that collects specific data from a website every day. I have already figured out how to take the data off the website, but I don't know how to make the loop to collect the data once a day.

I have looked into the time module, but I can't find out how to make a continuous loop that takes the data every day.

Edit: I am using windows. I could still try to use cron if there is a windows version for it, or something similar.

Comment: What you probably want to do is make a python program that collects data from the website for the current day, then use a job scheduler like [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run your script once a day

Comment: Well, I don't know too much about cron or task schedulers. I'd rather it just be in the python program. But thanks.

Comment: The cron-based approach is really the better one here. But if you want to stick to python, the core of your code would looke like this: ```while True: time.sleep(1) current_time = time.strftime(some_format) and some comparison```. The sleep-time itself will have an effect on performance. Sleeping for 1 second, loop, 1 second will not take noticable resourses. Sleeping for 0.001 secs will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time
while True:
    take_data()  # you provide this one
    time.sleep(24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)  # 24 hours in seconds
```

Comment: This will get out of synch over time due to other resources beeing handled on the system (e.g. at some time it might wait 25 hours; resulting in a shift of the time itself this runs on -> e.g. 3 at night -> 4 at night every night).

Comment: Sure, but if that's critical you can just call time.time() to get the current time, and then adjust the argument to time.sleep() so that you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, if I were to update to get current time, where and how would I do it?

Comment: The time.time() function returns a large float, which is the time in seconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970.  You can get a date and time of day by calling time.localtime() or time.gmtime().  There are many other time manipulation functions in the time and calendar modules.  Not much fun, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is actually a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) assuming you're working with a Unix/Linux OS. It's better to rely on technology that already exists instead of reinventing the wheel.

In short, it will perform a task that can be executed via the command line at pre-defined times in the day.

e.g.

```
# minute hour day month day-of-week  shell command
  0      0    *   *     *            script1.sh             # runs every day at midnight
  0      *    *   *     *            rm ~/trash/*           # runs at the top of every hour
  30     12   14  *     *            echo "hi!"             # runs at 12h30 on the 14th of every month
  10     1    *   *     1            script2.py             # runs every monday at 01h10
```

Comment: This approach (which i recommend) used like this (meaning your shell commands in example) would need a python shebang in the python-file, right?

Comment: that is correct but i usually wrap it in a shell script so i can activate a virtual environment before the script runs